# PHP isset() Safety

Tags: php

Is the act of calling `isset()` on `$_POST` and `$_GET` safe?

I am fully aware of the dangers of using `$_POST` and `$_GET` without filtering but I have often used `isset()` to test if the key I want actually exists. So I want to know if the side effects of `isset()` could cause problems.

Comment: Yes. You should never rely on it as your **only** form of validation though.

Comment: if you're testing for existence and being null then yes `isset()` is okay, but for other things which you didn't state? safety against what?

Comment: I am only referring to using `isset()` to check for existence. This is, in my head, the first step in ensuring that the data is valid. I wanted to know if by using `isset()` before filtering, that PHP injection can't occur by the act of calling `isset()`.

Comment: It can still occur. Isset only checks if a variable is set, that's it. It doesn't check what it contains.

Answer (score 1):

The principle of not relying on `$_POST` and `$_GET`, or any other user provided values for that matter, is one of not depending on them to take on a certain form.  For example, if you request a phone number from the user, you should not assume that the user provided something that even remotely resembles a phone number.

To take this further, just because there's a field on your form, don't assume that the user has provided that value and wantonly index into `$_POST` or `$_GET` to retrieve its value.  The user could be sending you anything.

Consequently, using `isset` to check keys before accessing them is the **safe** way to access `$_POST` and `$_GET`.  Otherwise you may index to a key which has not been set, which would allow users to induce errors in your application, which would be **unsafe** or, at the very least, **undesirable**.